# How can I make my Slideshow Indicators change their style with my current code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have had an issue with placing slideshows in my website. I require more than one slideshow on the same page which has led to multiple problems with the scrolling and such. I finally came across a solution which works almost perfectly however, the indicators do not change color to reflect the current slide.

```js
var w3 = {};
w3.slideshow = function (sel, ms, func) {
  var i, ss, x = w3.getElements(sel), l = x.length;
  ss = {};
  ss.current = 1;
  ss.x = x;
  ss.ondisplaychange = func;
  if (!isNaN(ms) || ms == 0) {
    ss.milliseconds = ms;
  } else {
    ss.milliseconds = 1000;
  }
  ss.start = function() {
    ss.display(ss.current)
    if (ss.ondisplaychange) {ss.ondisplaychange();}
    if (ss.milliseconds > 0) {
      window.clearTimeout(ss.timeout);
      ss.timeout = window.setTimeout(ss.next, ss.milliseconds);
    }
  };
  ss.next = function() {
    ss.current += 1;
    if (ss.current > ss.x.length) {ss.current = 1;}
    ss.start();
  };
  ss.previous = function() {
    ss.current -= 1;
    if (ss.current < 1) {ss.current = ss.x.length;}
    ss.start();
  };
  ss.display = function (n) {
    w3.styleElements(ss.x, "display", "none");
    w3.styleElement(ss.x[n - 1], "display", "block");
  }
  ss.start();
  return ss;
};
```

```html
<html>
<script src="w3.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="2" class="w3-row-padding w3-light-grey w3-padding-64 w3-container">
  <div class="w3-content">
   <div class="w3-content w3-display-container w3-center">
   
    <div class = "Slide2 w3-animate-opacity">
      <h1> Slide Content </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Second slide App Development -->
    <div class = "Slide2 w3-animate-opacity">
      <h1> Slide Content </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Third slide App Development -->
    <div class = "Slide2 w3-animate-opacity">
      <h1> Slide Content </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth slide App Development -->
    <div class = "Slide2 w3-animate-opacity">
      <h1> Slide Content </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-grey" style="width:100%">
   <span class="w3-left w3-hover-text-blue fa fa-arrow-left" onclick="myShow2 .previous()"></span>
   <span class="w3-right w3-hover-text-blue fa fa-arrow-right" onclick="myShow2 .next()"></span>
   <span class="fa fa-circle demo w3-hover-text-blue w3-transparent" onclick="myShow2 .display(1)"></span>
   <span class="fa fa-circle demo w3-hover-text-blue w3-transparent" onclick="myShow2 .display(2)"></span>
   <span class="fa fa-circle demo w3-hover-text-blue w3-transparent" onclick="myShow2 .display(3)"></span>
   <span class="fa fa-circle demo w3-hover-text-blue w3-transparent" onclick="myShow2 .display(4)"></span>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  </div>
  <script> myShow2 = w3.slideshow(".Slide2", 0); </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So the code works well and does what I want except I'm not sure how to make the circle indicators change to blue to reflect the current slide. I have tried completely different approaches except this is the only one that allows multiple slideshows on the same page. Could some please explain to me how I would go about making the circles stay blue when clicked and revert when another is clicked?

Comment: Your snippet unfortunately says that `w3` is undefined. Can you please provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's a little hard to work out exactly what the problem is when we can't replicate it :P

Comment: w3 is defined in the css except i'm unsure how to reference it in SO. The issue is more with the logic I feel.

Comment: w3 is defined in the CSS yes, but it is not defined in the JavaScript. Where are you initialising `var w3?` Are you using a framework or plugin? Do you have any code in addition to this?

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to select the var w3 {}; except it still doesn't work when executed on this. I went off of this site: https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3js_slideshow_next

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. First I added an extra variable to call a function `<script> myShow4 = w3.slideshow(".Slide4", 0, "demo4"); </script>`
the "demo4" will be used to find the indicator dots. `<span class="fa fa-circle demo4 w3-hover-text-blue w3-transparent" onclick="myShow4 .display(4)"></span>`each indicator has the specific class.

```
`ss.display = function (n) {
    ss.current = n;
    w3.styleElements(ss.x, "display", "none");
    w3.styleElement(ss.x[n - 1], "display", "block");
    ss.indicator(demo);
  }
  ss.indicator = function(n) {
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName(n);
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
         dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-text-blue", "");
      }
      x[ss.current-1].style.display = "block"; 
      dots[ss.current-1].className += " w3-text-blue";
  }`
```

This is the new code in the JS file. on click the display function is called and I edited the function to also call the indicator function which changes the current slide relevant dot to blue while changing the rest to nothing or how they were before. This solution worked for me, adding another function within the called function.